# Calculate 2D rotation javascript HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, angular, canvas, coordinates

Implemented a canvas, Drawing a square there and get the calculated coordinates,

 Can see on the following pic the drawing:
[image: canvas draw]

I'm calculating and getting the upleft point X and Y coordinates,

And for the down right coordinates that i need, I'm adding the height and width, as follows:

```
 { upLeft: { x: position.x, y: position.y }, downRight: { x: position.x + position.width, y: position.y + position.height } },
```

Now i want to get the same dimensions when i'm rotating the canvas clockwise or anti-clockwise.
So i have the angle, And i try to calculate via the following function:

```
 function getRotatedCoordinates(cx, cy, x, y, angle) {
    let radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle,
        cos = Math.cos(radians),
        sin = Math.sin(radians),
        nx = (cos * (x - cx)) - (sin * (y - cy)) + cx,
        ny = (cos * (y - cy)) + (sin * (x - cx)) + cy;
    return [nx, ny];
  }
```

And i'm calling the function via the following args and using it.

```
let newCoords = getRotatedCoordinates(0, 0, position.x, position.y, angle);
position.x = newCoords[0];
position.y = newCoords[1];
```

So firstly, I'm not sure that the cx and cy points are correct, I'm always entering 0 for both of them.
Secondly, I'm not getting the desired results, They are getting changed but i'm pretty sure that something is wrong with the x and y, So i guess that the function is wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: of course i'm using the results, thanks i will change that

Comment: @ChrisG thanks, look how i use it, I do change the position.x and position.y according to what i'm getting from the function already, So still have an issue there.

Comment: @ChrisG Indeed, But only here not in my actual code :).

Comment: _“I'm not sure that the cx and cy points are correct, I'm always entering 0 for both of them.”_ - then what effect do you expect them to have on your formulas there? And where did you get that function _from_ then, if you are not even sure what values for the input parameters would actually make sense; I’m assuming you did not actually write that yourself then?

Comment: @CBroe I didn't write this function, I didn't find any other function to calculate the matrix.
I guess that cx and cy are the initial point of the coordinates, and that's why i choose 0,0

Comment: If you rotate your canvas around its center point(?), but the rectangle is not the _same_ size as your canvas - then you will of course have to take the offset of the rectangle against the canvas center point into account in some way.

Comment: To be clear, the way you're using the function you're rotating the position vector around the origin. This code will definitely change the position as long as angle isn't zero, so the question is how you're using the new coordinates. Combined with your first snippet, you aren't rotating the rectangle, just moving around its top left corner. To rotate the rectangle you need to rotate all its for corners.

Comment: @CBroe This is what i thought, Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisG right, So my question would be, How do i rotate all the corners ?

Comment: You can translate and rotate the canvas instead, if this is only about drawing the rectangle. If you do need its coordinates to change, you need a different approach. Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/kyehsxm3/

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

```js
function getRectangeCoordinates(x, y, width, height, angle) {
  let points = [ [x, y] ]
  let radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    x += Math.cos(radians) * ((i == 1) ? height : width);
    y += Math.sin(radians) * ((i == 1) ? height : width);
    points.push([x, y])
    radians += Math.PI / 2
  }
  return points
}

let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 140
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

function draw(coords, radius) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], radius, 0, 8);
    ctx.moveTo(coords[i][0], coords[i][1]);
    let next = (i + 1) % 4
    ctx.lineTo(coords[next][0], coords[next][1]);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

let coords = getRectangeCoordinates(20, 10, 120, 40, 15)
console.log(JSON.stringify(coords))
draw(coords, 3)

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
coords = getRectangeCoordinates(60, 40, 40, 50, 65)
draw(coords, 5)

ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
coords = getRectangeCoordinates(120, 3, 20, 20, 45)
draw(coords, 2)
```

In the `getRectangeCoordinates` I'm returning all corners of a rectangle and the paraments of the function are the top left corner `(x, y)` the height and width of the rectangle and last the angle.

I'm drawing a few rectangles with different shapes and angles to show how it looks like

---

The calculations in the function are simple trigonometry here is a visual representation that could help you remember it the next time you need it:

[image]